# Dynamically choose api in mono for android

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

Is there any way to detect the current version of android and use one code path for one version, and another code path for a later version?

Something like ClipboardManager, there is a new version in API level 11, but the only way of accessing this new class is by telling mono for android that the minimum requirements is API level 11.

I "think" you can get around this using java reflection, but I imagine this wouldn't work when using Mono for Android. Has anyone got any advice on how you can use both ClipboardManager's, the early one on earlier versions, the later one on later versions, without setting the API level as 11 or higher.

This is a generic example, not limited to ClipboardManager. I am sure I will come across more classes that I could optionally use if it is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is. Just make sure to set your target API level in the manifest.

When wanting to use API 11 for instance you could do something like this:

```
if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 11)
{
    //Execute API 11 and up code here
}
```

However if you are using methods and classes that are only present in API 11, VS might complain that it cannot find them, so you can surround them with a pre-processor symbol like:

```
#if __ANDROID_11__
    // your API 11 and up code here
#endif
```